# Rigify error spine.004 after connecting two separate armatures into one metarig

Tags: rigify

When creating a metarig, the face on the original became displaced past the point of fixing, so I decided to delete the face bones, take the face of another rig, and join it to the body. In order to connect it to the spine, I used cursor to selected and selection to cursor. When I tried to generate rig though, I run into this error message. Any suggestions to fix this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the `spine.004` error happens when the `spine.003` (chest bone) is not aligned with the `spine.004` (first bone of the neck).

If they're not **perfectly** aligned (the top of `spine.003` with the base of `spine.004`), you will get an error. Open another Blender project with a fresh rigify rig and use it as a reference.

To perfectly align the two, select the top of `spine.003`, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select *Cursor to Selected*. Then select the base of `spine.004`, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and select *Selected to Cursor*. And that will align them perfectly.